# is there a copy command in bigquery like there is in snowflake?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In the past, I would frequently load s3 files in Snowflake using `COPY INTO` sql command.  This would allow me to inject values, such as the current timestamp.  Does bigquery not have this command?

Example I would use in Snowflake, the ability to create the batchtimestamp is important:

```
copy into my_db.my_schema.some_table (
    select
      current_timestamp as batchtimestamp,
      some_column,
      some_column2
    from @mys3.myfolder/something/blah/
)
file_format = (
    type = csv,
    field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'
```

Comment: Is that not SELECT INTO? The file_format part throws me off though.

Comment: Consider `LOAD DATA` statement in BigQuery. see here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#load_data_statement

Comment: You can use Load Data, you can also query external table (files in Cloud Storage here) without materializing the data in BigQuery tables, and you can also finally, query the data in External Tables (Cloud Storage) and save them in BigQuery (Insert select statements)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere are you aware of any way you can inject a batch_timestamp and batch_id during the load?

Comment: If you use schema autodetect, no, you can't. If you have an existing schema, you can create a default column with the current timestamp in it. for the batch ID, I don't know any solution...

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaytiger mentioned  in the comment you can consider the LOAD DATA statement in BigQuery.

For example:

```
LOAD DATA INTO mydataset.table1
  FROM FILES(
    format='CSV',
    uris = ['gs://bucket/path/file1.csv', 'gs://bucket/path/file2.csv']
  )
```

You can also consider using an External table as @guillaume blaquiere mentioned. For more information you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#load_data_statement),[link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBfx1K3-97k) and [link3](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#sql).

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.